# Почему в коде страницы старые, удаленные изображения?

Tags: wordpress

На самой странице все поменялось. Картинка новая. Я чистила кеш в админке. Открывала сайт в разных браузерах, но в коде все равно старая картинка. Мне нужно чтобы ФБ публиковал новые изменения, но в коде старая картинка, поэтому побликует со старой картинкой.

В чем может быть причина?

Сайт на вордпресс

Comment: А если обновить страничку при помощи Ctrl + F5, картинка обновится?

Comment: нет, не обновляется

Comment: невнимательно прочитал вопрос. У вас в самомо коде html остаются данные о старой картинке. Моя ошибка.

Comment: да, именно так. На самой странице все ок. Но ФБ берет информацию из кода.

Comment: @Юля Кэш почистите браузером или нажмите cntrl+f5

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что можно как-то почистить кеш в админке с помощью браузера? Я с других браузеров смотрела - везде в коде старая картинка. Комбинация с cntrl+f5 не помогает.

Comment: Давайте проясним что Вы имеете ввиду под "в коде все равно старая картинка", если Вы в тоже время говорите что на странице все ок. Наверное Вы имеете ввиду какой-то специфический кусочек кода, особенно если речь о ФБ, то наверное Вы говорите об Open Graph.

Comment: Я проверяю на наличие новой картинки, ее тоже нет ( в коде). Вообще. В отладчике ФБ тоже старая картинка, которая даже удалена из админки. Но на самой странице все нормально, картинка какая нужна. В коде нет новой картинке вообще, то есть в тегах og.imag . И вообще не видно, когда я ищу через контр+F

Comment: Я первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь. Обычно бывает - в коде все ок, а на странице нет. Тогда достаточно почистить кеш, и изменения появятся. Но в данном случае в коде нет изменений, а на странице есть.

Comment: Название и размер изображения совершенно другое.